# Django 'title_en' is not in list

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, mezzanine, django-modeltranslation

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/blog/blog-title/
Django Version: 1.10.8
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
'title_en' is not in list
Exception Location: /lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __init__, line 1715
Python Executable:  /bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.5
```

after installing `django-modeltranslation` i am getting this error on my django site.
I have tried adding fields in translationOptions. Also tried makemigration and migrations. This adds the title_en in table however it's not rendering the blog on the front.
Before adding `django-modeltranslation` the blogs were being rendered properly without any error.

Answer (score 0):

When you add `model-translation` to existing models, which already contain data, the data is still stored in the original column (e.g. `title`) but not copied to the new default language column `title_en`.

So if you're migrating existing data, after `makemigrations` and `migrate` you should also run `update_translation_fields` which will copy any existing values into the empty default language columns.

You can run this multiple times (when adding translation to other models later), it only copies values when the `_en` field is empty.

Comment: Note that for your specific `ValueError` above, you need to show us the code of the line where the error occurs, seems you're hard-coding the field name `title` somewhere and it's now replaced with `title_en` (or `title_fr` if the user sets his language to French) so you have to be careful about this.